# Odoo Treeview Colors&Font

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9

In Odoo 9 I changed the treeview based on a field. This works but I would also like to make the font bold. I read that the decortion-bf can be combined to make the colors stand out better.

```
<tree string="Status" decoration-danger="status=='open'"
            decoration-success="status=='complete'"
            decoration-info="status=='progress'"
            decoration-warning="status=='response'"
            decoration-primary="status=='pickup'">
                <field name="x_partner_id"/>
                <field name="status" editable="true"/>
                <field name="create_date"/>
            </tree>
```

I tried

```
<tree string="Status" decoration-danger="status=='open'"
            decoration-success-bf="status=='complete'"
            decoration-info-bf="status=='progress'"
            decoration-warning-bf="status=='response'"
            decoration-primary-bf="status=='pickup'">
                <field name="x_partner_id"/>
                <field name="status" editable="true"/>
                <field name="create_date"/>
            </tree>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `decoration-bf` should be set separately [[source](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/6108778497af2ecfec1df7f9fdfb0f89f08c1a51/openerp/addons/base/rng/view.rng#L254-L261)], so you could write something like this:

```xml
<tree string="Status" decoration-danger="status=='open'"
        decoration-success="status=='complete'"
        decoration-info="status=='progress'"
        decoration-warning="status=='response'"
        decoration-primary="status=='pickup'"
        decoration-bf="status in ('complete', 'progress', 'response', 'pickup')">
    <field name="x_partner_id"/>
    <field name="status" editable="true"/>
    <field name="create_date"/>
</tree>
```